# Method returns NULL value for object list

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, null

I am attempting to learn Java JBDC by developing a web application using `jsp` and `servlet` files. Currently I want to return a list of `Category` objects, where these `Objects` represent a row in the `ResultSet`. Each row should contain `cat_id` and `cat_name`.

The `crm_categories` table looks like this in the MySQL database.

[image: Example of crm_categories table]

In the index.jsp file I instantiate a `JDBC` and call the `getCategories()` method like so:

```
dbCon conn          = new dbCon();
List<Object> catList;

// get a list of all categories
catList = conn.getCategories();
```

The following is the `dbCon` class which I have simplified:

```
@WebServlet(description = "Handles connection to MySql database", urlPatterns = { "/dbh" })
public class dbCon extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static Connection conn; 
    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", host = "jdbc:mysql://hostname/", dbName = "dbname", username = "name", password = "pow"; 
String sql;
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement prep;
Post post;
Category cat;
List<Object> catList;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public dbCon() {
    try{
        rs = null;
        prep = null;
        conn = getConnection();

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
    try{
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(host + dbName, username, password);
        return conn;
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conn;
  }

public List<Object> getCategories() throws Exception{
    try{
        this.catList = new ArrayList<Object>();

        sql = "SELECT cat_id, cat_name FROM crm_categories";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            cat = new Category();
            cat.setAttributes(rs.getInt("cat_id"), rs.getString("cat_name"));
            catList.add(cat);
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return catList;
}
```

Category Class:

```
@WebServlet("/Category")
public class Category extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Category() {
        name        = null;
        id          = 0;
    }

    public void setAttributes(int id, String name){
        this.name       = name;
        this.id         = id;
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me why the `getCategories()` method is returning a `null` value for the `catList`?

Answer (score 0):

Is the `getCategories()` method catching an exception ?

If that is the case, the returned `catList` is `null` because `this.catList = new ArrayList<Object>();` has been done within the try block. Moving the object instantiation before the try block should fix your null pointer issue.

Comment: I don't believe so, atleast when I run the server no error stacktrace is printed to the web browser.

Comment: I edited my answer, try moving the object instantiation outside the try block. You may get an empty list though, but i can't see how you could possibly get a null pointer returned if you do so.

Comment: @crm printStackTrace prints to stdout (stderr?).  Unless you've redirected that elsewhere, look at your console.  the stack trace would not be sent to the browser unless you specifically designed it to do so.

Comment: `catList` is still `null` even when I move it outside of the try/catch.